# Who started the "-oid" suffix fashion in math?

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology

There are lots of structures which have name suffixed by "oid".  Off the top of my head, matroid, greedoid, perfectoid, causaloid...

Who started this? AFAIK, "matroid", by Whitney, was a start, and led the way to several combinatorial oids.  However, the [Cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) has had its name for some centuries now, so the use of the suffix is old.

Still, it seems a bit different to name a family of specific objects, and to name some sort of abstract structure.

Comment: Brandt Introduced groupoids in 1926 but he wrote in German and maybe used some Germanic equivalent suffix rather than oid.

Comment: The only consistent use of the -oid suffix I know is for Horizontal categorication (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification), so typically, groupoid, algebroid, ringoid, etc... in which case the origin is definitely the name "groupoid". But it is unclear if all the examples you mention fit into this picture ? Otherwise the use of -oid to name "something vaguely ressembling something else" does not strike me as really being a fashion nor being specific to mathematics.

Comment: Of course the horizontal categorification of monoid is category and not monoidoid :)

Comment: Ellipsoids, paraboloids and hyperboloids have been around for a long time.

Comment: **spheroid** 1664 Barrow.  From Latin sphaeroīdēs, from Greek σϕαιροειδής   The *Oxford English Dictionary* says the -oid suffix is used primarily in mathematics and in  zoology.

Comment: At the first place the suffix -oid is not mathematical (https://www.dictionnaire.exionnaire.com/que-signifie.php?mot=-oide). My favorite mathematical one anyway, in French, is [patatoïde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patato%C3%AFde), one of the most important geometric shapes in the whole history.

Comment: Perhaps this is  more appropriate for Mathoid Overflow. It's not really a math question...

Comment: Here is [Mathoid Overflow](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) as Donu suggested :)

Comment: My guess would be Rutherford in his universal algebra, the precursor to model theory. Were an algebra is a set with binary operation and various logical properties of some formal logic etc, specific these logical properties are, I think they abstract groups basically. I would imagine if Rutherford didn't use the word monoid, he probably started the notions which would lead to it and it's eventual naming.

Comment: Of course parabloids etc pre-empt all of this as Michael renarsy said.

Comment: Given the endless quest for more levels of abstraction, it's only a matter of time before somebody writes a paper about oidoids.

Comment: Sorry I meant Russel not Rutherford.

Comment: Let's remember about dendroidoid. ...

Comment: [Trapezoid vs trapezium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) is IMHO the most peculiar one.

Comment: *X-oid < X-oeidēs* was already used in Ancient Greek as a suffix meaning 'looking like X', from eido 'to see'. https://www.etymonline.com/word/-oid

Comment: @alephzero *[suffixoid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suffixoid)* is a [word used in linguistics](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Linguistics/mUdqAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=suffixoid&dq=suffixoid&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 55):

The suffix "-oid" means the same as "quasi", so "resembling", "like". A *groupoid* is a quasi-group, like a group. There are [hundreds of words](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-oid) in that category, covering many scientific disciplines.

In the "early use of mathematical words" [database](https://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) I find:

250 BC: conchoid
200 BC: cissoid
400: trapezoid
1650: trochoid
1672: ellipsoid
1685: cochleoid
1830: epicycloid
1836: paraboloid
1837: strophoid
1844: centroid
1872: geoid, gyroid
1878: nephroid
1879: deltoid
1881: prismatoid
1891: cuboid
1935: matroid

[The Woid on-Oid](https://www.nytimes.com/1984/02/05/magazine/on-language-the-woid-on-oid.html) by William Safire comments on the proliferation of -oids:

> We all know that the use of -oid to create a noun has been growing by
> leapoids and bounds. Among the earliest were android, or "automaton
> in human form," created in 1727, and asteroid, "small body like a
> star," in 1802. Scientists and mathematicians were especially
> attracted to the ending, juggling their cylindroids, globoids and
> spheroids.

Comment: (I took '-oid' out of math mode; I hope that was OK.)  I wouldn't have expected cuboid to be so late!  The first ones that occurred to me were ellipsoid and spheroid; I wonder (but not enough to check) when they first occurred.

Comment: Also, purely mathematically, a groupoid is not a quasi-group, I think.  :-)

Comment: On the other hand, the empty set (which can be described by the word v-oid) is relatively recent.

Comment: First, thanks (not a thankoid) to all who answered.  Still, the list presented in the answer above sort of reinforces my question, albeit slightly rephrased:


Is "matroid" the first oid-named abstract structure?

Comment: @ArnaldoMandel No, as already commented by Benjamin Steinberg that distinction may belong to groupoid (Brandt, [12 Dec 1925](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=GDZPPN002271125), p. 361): “Eine solche Menge miteinander verknüpfte Elemente soll ***Gruppoid*** heißen, wenn...”

Comment: @LSpice I wonder whether every groupoid that is also a quasi-group has to be a group?

Comment: This suggests that *Nicomedes* is the right answer to the question, since he was the one who first talked about conchoids.

Comment: I bet the shortest name that fits the bill is [oloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid) disovered 1929 by Paul Schatz

Answer (score 4):

Though this might not be what you are expecting, I will explain you "oidification" or horizontal categorification as I understood (Experts are fell free to add or edit as necessary). This is the process that generalizes a "certain type of category with a single object" to "such type of categories with multiple objects". This is done mostly via "enriching" the initial category $\mathcal{C}$ over another monoidal category $\mathcal{K},$ which roughly says homsets (set of arrows two objects) of $\mathcal{C}$ are replaced by objects of $\mathcal{K}.$

Examples include

| *X* | *X*-oid | Enrichment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| monoid | Category | categories enriched over **Set** |
| Category | 2-Category | categories enriched over **Cat** |
| Group | Groupoid |  |
| Ring | Ringoid | category enriched in tensor category **Ab** |
| Quantale | Quantaloid | category enriched in suplattices |
| Algebr | Algebroid | category enriched in **Vect** or *R***Mod** |
| *C*<sup>*</sup>-algebra | *C*<sup>*</sup>-category | *-category enriched in **Ban** |

You can find more details [ringoid,](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/09/ringoids.html) and [algebroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-algebroid) here. But as far as I know Hopf algebroids and Lie algebroids does not fit into this general definition of algebroids, but still multi-object generalizations of their counterparts.

Also, it should worth remind that not every enrichment of a categories consider as an "odification". For example (Lawvere) generalized metric spaces is a  category enriched in the monoidal poset category $([0,\infty],\ge),$ where the monoidal product is taken to be addition.

Comment: when will we see a *categoroid*?

Comment: @ManfredWeis It [already](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6295) [happened](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06853).